# How to Solve a System of Absolute Value Equations Algebraically

Tags: systems-of-equations, absolute-value

How can one find the points of intersections of the two graphs algebraically?

$$f(x) = |(x-1)^2-4|$$

$$f(x) = |x+3|-2$$

I understand that it could be solved graphically and through some sort of system of piecewise functions,

$$f(x) = $$
\begin{cases}
(x-1)^2-4,  & \text{if $x \le -1$ or $x \ge 3$ } \\
-(x-1)^2+4|, & \text{if $-1\lt x \lt 3$}
\end{cases}

$$g(x) = $$
\begin{cases}
x+1,  & \text{if $x \ge -3$} \\
-x-5, & \text{if $x \lt -3$}
\end{cases}

but is there a clean algebraic way to solve it?

Comment: I would just solve it as a system of piecewise  functions

Comment: I would do as @andrei say. Look at each branch of the piecewise functions and compare each on their intervals.

Comment: You have a typo in the last line. Should be $-x-5$ if $x<-3$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I think your answer is just "no"